# Creating a browser game (2D top-down perspective) without programming skills

Tags: linux, open-source, game-development

I’m looking for a tool that allows to create a game *without* programming skills.

The tool …

- must run natively on **GNU/Linux**
- must be **FLOSS**

The created game …

- must be a [**browser game**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_game)
  (mobile support not needed)
- must **not** require browser plugins (like Flash or Java) for playing
  (requiring modern browsers is okay)

I can imagine that only very limited games can be created without programming, but that’s okay. My goal is not to create a perfect game realizing all my ideas, but to get *something* that works, with as little effort as possible. So it’s totally fine if the tool comes with constraints, as long as it …

- allows creating a game with **[2D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_computer_graphics) [top-down perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_graphics#Top-down_perspective)**
  (similar to games like [Secret of Mana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_of_Mana) and many [RPG Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPG_Maker) creations)
- allows to **move** the player character with keyboard keys
  (<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>)
- allows the player character to **talk** with [NPCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-player_character)
  (at best with support for [dialog trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_tree))

Comment: Actually [in my question you have commented](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/76262/any-open-source-editor-to-make-video-games-online-without-programming-knowledge?noredirect=1#comment147178_76262) I write about two editors (Construct 2 or GameSalad Creator). I think both of them allow to export the game in HTML5, so you could use it in a web browser.

Comment: @chelder: In this question here I’m looking for (1) Free/Libre Open Source solutions that run on (2) GNU/Linux, and if I’m not mistaken, the tools you mentioned in your question are proprietary and not for Linux. -- However, I keep these in mind in case I shouldn’t find a suitable solution here, so thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

A couple of options to consider, for starters:

- [Gameblox](https://gameblox.org/) - blocks-based programming program to make games online. It's being developed at the [MIT STEP Lab](http://mitstep.org/) and is used by the [Design and Development of Games for Learning](https://www.edx.org/course/design-development-games-learning-mitx-11-127x) course on [edX](http://edx.org).
- [Godot engine](http://www.godotengine.org/projects/godot-engine) - advanced, feature packed, multi-platform 2D and 3D game engine. It provides a huge set of common tools, so you can just focus on making your game without reinventing the wheel.
- [Snap!](https://snap.berkeley.edu/) - JavaScript based, drag-and-drop code editor. Built to teach programming through animation and game design, and used in the [Beauty and Joy of Computing](http://bjc.berkeley.edu/) course from University of California, Berkeley.

Comment: Why did you make this CW?

Comment: So that other people can add to the answer. There may be other options than the ones I found :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have [some JavaScript experience](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1591669/unor?tab=tags), have you considered [ProcessingJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing.js)? Yes, it uses a programming language, but it is

- browser-based, thus runs on Linux,
- very simple to get started,
- can listen to key events,
- allows easy drawing of sprites, etc to the screen.

License: MIT.

If you would like a (very mellow) introduction, have a look at [Khan Academy's Intro to JS: Drawing & Animation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming) course.